# Show onboarding for new users

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am showing a transparent background activity on the top of my Android Main Activity. This transparent activity has some animation and it highlight the part of a main screen with 100% transparent colour background

This way I can inform more about the feature for new comers.

The only thing that I don't know is how to show the highlighted part with no 20% black colour.

[image]

My android layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/backgroundView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black_20">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSuccess"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@color/accent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Use estimation cards for your user stories."
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Got it." />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_user_estimation"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: One thing is, you can use same layout in transparent activity and make visible only those whom you want to highlight and set other invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@color/colorBlackShaded"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_user_estimation"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

and

```
<color name="colorBlackShaded">#33000000</color>
```

you can change the transparency as per you requirement using below snipet
like for 20% black use ***33*** for transparency and ***000000*** for black color

```
  100% — FF
  95% — F2
  90% — E6
  85% — D9
  80% — CC
  75% — BF
  70% — B3
  65% — A6
  60% — 99
  55% — 8C
  50% — 80
  45% — 73
  40% — 66
  35% — 59
  30% — 4D
  25% — 40
  20% — 33
  15% — 26
  10% — 1A
  5%  — 0D
  0% —  00
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use great libraries like this

https://github.com/iammert/MaterialIntroView

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4178

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/243 (I have used this in past)

They have really nice features.